# F# type constraint with Enum type

Tags: generics, enums, f#

I would like to write an F# function that takes a generic enum value and, let's say, doubles its underlying integer value. Fortunately, there's a built-in function called `int` that converts an enum to an integer, so this should be easy, right? Here's my first attempt:

```
let doubler (value : 't when 't : enum<int>) =
    2 * (int value)
```

Sadly, this results in the following compiler messages:

> Program.fs(2,10): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be
> less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable
> 't has been constrained to be type 'int'.
>
> Program.fs(2,10): error FS0071: Type constraint mismatch when applying
> the default type 'int' for a type inference variable. The type 'int'
> is not a CLI enum type. See also Program.fs(1,28)-(1,42). Consider
> adding further type constraints

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to extract the underlying integer from a generic enum value in F#?

Comment: What `enum` does is convert a value to its representation. The compiler will put the constraint in for you. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `EnumToValue`.

```
open FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives

let doubler xEnum =
        2 * EnumToValue(xEnum)

type ColorEnum =    
            | Red=0 
            | Yellow=1 
            | Blue=2

let blue = ColorEnum.Blue

doubler blue
//val it : int = 4
```

And if you examine the type signature of the `doubler`:

> val doubler : xEnum:'a -> int when 'a : enum

Regarding your first error, `int` is special, in a sense that it's a function as well. As you point out, you can use an underlying type constraint in the enum, but in that case be explicit about the type, so there is no confusion:

```
let double2 (x:'T when 'T:enum<int32>) =
   2 * EnumToValue(x)
```

Unfortunately you will still not be able to cast to `int` without using `EnumToValue`. Could be a compiler issue, or something else. Maybe the internals of EnumToValue can give a hint?

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks. Still seems odd that my code doesn't work, though.

Comment: @brianberns That's because there is no generic Enum (I think). If you want to constraint you would need to say `let doubl2 (x:'T when 'T:enum<ColorEnum>) =`. This would constraint x to be only one type of Enum though. And you would still bump into the `int` issue. I don't know the root cause of that.

Comment: What i mean is that there is no such thing as `enum<int>`. You could of course steal the type signature, and make it explicit: `let tripler (xEnum:'a when 'a:enum<_>)  =
        3 * EnumToValue(xEnum)`. But even without it the compiler will give you an error with char enums for example. To be frank, I haven't really had the need to use enums in F#, because there are DUs, maybe except for command line arguments.

Comment: I don't follow you. I'm pretty sure that `enum<int>` is a legal type constraint in F#, although the doc says it's "not intended for common use." See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Indeed. Let me ammend the answer though.

Comment: One other comment on this: It turns out that `EnumToValue` boxes the enum and then unboxes it as an int. This works fine, but is slow. What I'd really like is something that performs as well as the native `int` operator, which takes no cycles at runtime.

Comment: @brianberns Performance is a feature :-). Can you at least parallelize it? There might be of course a better way. Why don't you make another question with some benchmark numbers and an idea of what would be acceptable performance for you.