# F# Constrain generic parameter to be an enum type

Tags: generics, f#

I'm trying to create a generic method to convert an `Option<TEnum>` to a `Nullable<int>`:

```
let toNullableInt (value : Option<'T>) =
   if value.IsSome then Nullable(int value.Value) else Nullable()
```

The compiler infers that this is an `Option<int> -> Nullable<int>`

Is it possible to add a constraint to `'T` so that I can use it for enums?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# type constraint with Enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357587/f-type-constraint-with-enum-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible (kind of):

```
let toNullableInt (v : Option<'T> when 'T:> Enum) =
    if v.IsSome then Nullable(v.Value |> unbox |> int) else Nullable()
```

and quick check confirms that indeed:

```
type MyVals = 
| MyVal = 1000

MyVals.MyVal |> Option<MyVals>.Some |> toNullableInt
> 
val it : Nullable<int> = 1000

Option<MyVals>.None |> toNullableInt
> 
val it : Nullable<int> = null
```

<s>Unfortunately, this approach does not anyhow address the issue that an instance of enumerated type can have a value not defined within the enumeration, which the following expression illustrates by properly casting some alien `int`</s>:

```
enum</s><MyVals>10 |> Option<MyVals>.Some |> toNullableInt
> 
val it : Nullable<int> = 10
```

<s>while you'd probably wish getting `null` instead...</s>

**UPDATE:**
The author of the question found self how to fit in the check for "undefined" enumeration values and I just reproduce below the final solution taken from his comment below for better visibility:

```
let toNullableInt (v : Option<'T> when 'T:> Enum) =
    match v with
   | Some x when Enum.IsDefined (typeof<'T>, x) -> 
        Nullable(LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue(x))
   | _ -> Nullable ()
```

The given earlier check with an "alien" enum value input behaves now as desired:

```
enum<MyVals>10 |> Option<MyVals>.Some |> toNullableInt
>
val it : Nullable<int> = null
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ``v.IsSome`` will fail when ``v`` is ``None`` (at least when compiled in Release mode) because ``None`` will be represented as ``null``. Better use a construct like the following: ``match v with Some x when Enum.IsDefined (typeof<'T>, x) -> Nullable (int x) | _ -> Nullable ()``

Comment: Thanks! This works for me:
`let toNullableInt (v : Option<'T> when 'T:> Enum) =
            match v with 
                | Some x when Enum.IsDefined (typeof<'T>, x) -> Nullable (LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue(x) ) 
                | _ -> Nullable ()`

Comment: @dumetrulo - your statement "`v.IsSome` will fail when `v` is `None`" doesn't stay at least on current `VS2015 Ent ver 14.0.25431.01 Upd 3` where `Option.None.IsSome` being compiled in Release mode happily returns `false`.
And further, if you try your suggestion as a body to `let toNullableInt (v : Option<'T> when 'T:> Enum)` it simply will not compile with `Type constraint mismatch...`

Comment: @severin - right, the little trick with `LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue(x)` does its job effectively eliminating the need of enum augmentation. I'll update my answer accordingly.